# Position: fixed handled differently by Safari vs. Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I have a React app in which, after you scroll past a shopping cart, it becomes fixed to stay in view.

In Chrome, upon becoming fixed, the cart needs a `transform: translateX(-100%)` to retain its X-position. In Safari, it doesn't, and applying the rule causes the cart to misalign.

A stripped example can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/du167r85/ -- the cart becomes fixed after 1 second.

---

**Fiddle result on Chrome:**
[image: Fiddle result on Chrome]

**Fiddle result on Safari:**
[image: Fiddle result on Safari]

If the element is fixed from the start (e.g. without a timer or scroll event), Safari and Chrome render it the same, both requiring the `transform: translateX(-100%)` rule.

Is this a bug, and there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one of your problems is that you haven't defined a position left or right for your fixed element.

Give `right: 60px;` to your `#cart` and comment `-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);`

Here's and updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alezucc/a5tjwLye/5/)

Tested both on Safari and Chrome and it's working fine.

Another thing I would do is to move the `position: fixed;` up to `#cart-wrap`. I tried it as well and it still works fine!

Comment: Wow, thanks! On a side note, the reason for the `#cart-wrap` to even exist is because I use it as a `ref` in React to see when the user has scrolled passed that point.